# How to send information over to Widget inside Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget, widgetkit

I was trying to make my variables from the main app availible to the widget but it never seemed to work and always stayed at the starting value even after updating the widget.

I have tried to use UserDefaults and App Groups and it didn't work for either. I have an App Group called "group.com.dataPruducts" containing an UserDefaults called “setWidget". I have checked and inside the Main app the Objects inside the array exist but inside the Widget Extension not.

```
struct Provider: IntentTimelineProvider {
    func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var pruductsList: [String] = []
        if let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.dataPruducts") {
            pruductsList = userDefaults.array(forKey: "setWidget") as? [String] ?? []
            userDefaults.synchronize()
            print("Sync Successfull!")
        } else {
            pruductsList = []
            print("Sync failed!")
        }

        // Generate the timeline with the latest data
        var entries: [ChecklistEntry] = []
        // ... generate entries here ...
        let Checkeds = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "Checked") as? [Bool] ?? []
        let Pruducts = pruductsList
        // For example, you can loop through your products and create entries like this:
        let entry = ChecklistEntry(
            date: Date(),
            configuration: configuration,
            pruduct: pruductsList,
            checked: Checkeds,
            checkedCount: Checkeds.filter { $0 }.count,
            itemCount: Pruducts.count
        )
        entries.append(entry)
        
        // Use the entries array to create the timeline
        print("reload!")
        print(pruductsList)
        print(UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "Checked") as? [Bool] ?? [])
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .never)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}

struct ChecklistEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let configuration: ConfigurationIntent
    let pruduct: [String]
    let checked: [Bool]
    let checkedCount: Int
    let itemCount: Int
}

struct MicroListEntryView : View {
    var entry: ChecklistEntry

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ContainerRelativeShape()
                .fill(.orange.gradient)
            VStack {
                Text("Done: \(entry.checkedCount)")
                Text("Left: \(entry.itemCount - entry.checkedCount)")
                if entry.checkedCount == entry.itemCount {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Finished: ")
                        Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                    }
                }
                if entry.checkedCount != entry.itemCount {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Finished: ")
                        Image(systemName: "xmark")
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```